# Getting errors while trying to retrieve data from mysql database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to retrieve the data from mysql database using PDO but I am getting errors.

Here is the code

```
 <form id="form" action="sum1.php" method="post">
 <td><p align="center"> IDNO : <input type="text" name="id" id="id" maxlength="10"</p></td>
 <input type="submit" id="submit" class='btnExample' value="Click here to get your Result">
  </form> 
  <?PHP 
  $dbhost     = "localhost";
  $dbname     = "demo";
  $dbuser     = "admin";
  $dbpass     = "123456";
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", "$dbuser", "$dbpass");
  $id = $_POST['id']; 
  $add = $db->prepare("SELECT SUM(tech) AS tech4 FROM (
  (SELECT SUM(tm) AS tech FROM jbit WHERE htno > :id)
  UNION ALL
  (SELECT SUM(tm) AS tech FROM hmm WHERE htno > :id))t1");
  $add -> execute(array('id'=>$id));
  $result3 = $db->query($add);
  echo " <center><table id='mytable' cellspacing='0'  border=3 align=center> 
  <tr><TH scope='col'>Total Marks</TH> </tr><center>"; 
  while ($row1 = $result3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
   echo "<tr>"; 
   echo "<td align=center>" . $row1['tech4']. "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
   $result3->closeCursor();
   $db = null;
   ?>
```

ERRORS I am getting

```
Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in /home/nhtsoft/public_html/engineershub/sum1.php on line 17
```

and

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/nhtsoft/public_html/engineershub/sum1.php on line 20
```

17th Line is

```
$result3 = $db->query($add);
```

20th line is

```
while ($row1 = $result3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all fix this

```
 $add -> execute(array('id'=>$id)); 
  //and remove 
 $result3 = $db->query($add);
```

And use

```
 $add -> execute(array(':id'=>$id));
  while($result=$add->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

Comment: yah done, now there are no errors but still the output is blank

Comment: @Aryan might be due to empty result by your query.Try to run this query in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Got the output .. thankyou soo much but showing incorrect output, while using Mysql queries i am getting exact output but by using PDO i am getting wrong output. could u please check the query once

Answer (score 1):

This is how to use prepared statements:

```
$add = $db->prepare(...);
$add->execute(array('id' = >$id));
while ($row = $add->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) ...
```

`execute()` already executes the query. `PDO::query()` is for firing off a non-prepared query directly. You do not need it here.

Comment: yah done , now there are now errors but still output is blank